# Using jQuery with angular 2 projects

Tags: jquery, angular

I wanted to use ng2bootstrap with my angular 2 project but ran into the issue of it requiring jQuery library?

I am really not sure if it is a good idea to mix jQuery and angular2 since we had jQLite in A1 but nothing of that sort in A2.

Please advice. I will not use jQuery in my project apart from support for 3rd party libs.

Comment: Some of things still need jquery support like [Angular Datatable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/). In my suggestion you can use jquery for specific page where you need it.

Comment: Sure. But are there any known pitfalls of combing them both?

Comment: PrimeNG has jquery in some component's dependencies and it's working really well. I guess you can use it freely.